# "Shade" vs. "shadow"

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns

What are the differences between *shade* and *shadow*? Do they have different meanings or can they be used interchangeably?

> Let's sit under the **shade/shadow**.
>
> The cat was afraid of its own **shade/shadow**.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A shadow is the silhouette cast by an object that blocks a source of light.  You can see your shadow on the ground or a wall or whatever you are blocking from the light source.  You can make shadow puppets with your hands.  A shadow can be cast by any light source such as a candle, a flashlight, an overhead light, a spotlight, or the sun.

Shade is the "darkness" created by a shadow and only really applies to shadows created outside by the sun.  Underneath a tree on a sunny day would be "in the shade".  Inside a building would be "out of the sun" and not "in the shade."  However, under a roof with no walls (like a picnic shelter) would be "in the shade."

Answer (score 18):

When used as a verb in the sense of "cast a shadow", shade and shadow can be used interchangeably. The trees shadow/shade the road.

When used as a noun, *shade* is relative darkness, *shadow* is what causes the darkness. A tree casts a *shadow* which causes *shade*. *Shade* is *shadowiness*.  A *shadow* is *shade within clear boundaries.*

Historically they were the same word. In Old English, nouns were inflected, they had different forms depending on usage. The Old English noun *sceadu* (shade/shadow) became *sceaduwe* (in shade/shadow) when preceded by a preposition. Over time, the two word forms became interpreted as different words. The same process happened to the words *mead* and *meadow*. The uninflected form became archaic and is now used only poetically. (Mead in the sense of fermented honey has a different origin.)

So depending on context or idiom, they can't usually be used as a noun interchangeably. As well, each word has taken on other *shades* of meaning which aren't really equivalent. (Couldn't resist.)

Answer (score 4):

What you probably want is

> Let's sit under the shade

and

> The cat was afraid of its own shadow.

A shadow of an object is formed on the ground when the object prevents the sun's rays from reaching the ground. A shade is an object used to shelter you from the sun.

However, *shade* is also used as an uncountable noun to refer to an area of darkness formed under a cover with the intention of keeping something cool, in which case one would use *sit in the shade* though *sit under the shade* is also possible.

Comment: This is not quite complete. *Shade* is also what shadows are made of. “Let’s sit in the shade.” “101° in the sun, but 80° in the shade.”

Comment: I would probably not describe an umbrella as "a shade". I would say "an umbrella will give us some shade".

Comment: a shade (especially one belonging to a person/animal) could be interpreted as a ghost/supernatural thing

Answer (score 2):

Shade often deals with being sheltered from the sun and does not necessarily have  strongly defined edges. A shadow may have more defined edges but aren't necessarily cast from the sun.

Answer (score 2):

(BrE) Jasper Loy has made me realise that there might be some confusion here, as *shade* can have two meanings. There's the *shade* that Eric and ghoppe are talking about, which is sort of indefinite, for example from a group of trees, as opposed to the *shadow* from a single tree.

I think that is what would normally first come to mind for a native speaker.  It's what you look for on a hot day. But here I would usually say sitting *in the shade*, not *under the shade*.

And then there's what Jasper is talking about, which we would normally call, I think, a sunshade. This is a bit like a large umbrella or parasol, and which you would indeed *sit under*.

@ghoppe - Oh, I do like *shades of meaning* - I've just been listening to 'Round the Horne' on the BBC. Do you know it? That joke would have been perfect for him.

Answer (score 2):

A **shadow** is a dark shape made by something that blocks the sun or a light
    • She saw his shadow on the wall.
 A **shadow** also is an area of darkness made like this
    • The side of the valley was in shadow.
A **shade** is a cool dark area where the sun does not reach, made by the shadow of something such as a tree or wall
    • Let's eat our lunch in the shade.
• He sat under the shade of a tree.

source: [***Longman dictionary***](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/shade_1)

Answer (score 1):

I can only says that a tree blocking the sun brings about shade and the shade it brings is its shadow, which varies with the sun and time of day.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, in illustration, a shadow is a dark area cast by an object on another surface while shade is the dark, unlit area on the side of the object that casts the shadow.